# Facebook like button giving error - Website inaccessible

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This isn't the first time this has happened for me and now I really need to get it sorted. I'm trying to get a like button on a site I'm working on for this facebook page:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/JuJu-London/105631147168

I have already used the facebook lint tool and all it says is it's inaccessible, which is no use to me whatsoever.

Does anyone know why it is being "inaccessible" even though I can access and like the page if I go to it through the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inaccessible for me either.
http://www.facebook.com/pages/JuJu-London/105631147168 directs me to my FB home page

It looks it's some kind of secret group and their lint works like normal user

Comment: After reading this I went and checked what was going wrong. It was due to the age restriction being set. Thanks

Comment: @sn0lan: and it's still there :)